# cant access wordpress directory in wamp server www folder from localhost

Tags: wordpress, networking, windows-7, localhost, wampserver

I have a 32bit Win7.

I am trying to set Wordpress 4.1 up to work on Wampserver 2.5.

I copied the extracted wordpress files into my own folder within the c:wamp/www folder. But after going to the localhost page, clicking on my folder under 'Your Projects'  opens to a 'This Page Is Not Available' page, which cites either non-connectivity (not the case), or misconfigured network, or unresponsive DNS network or firewall issue.

I tried looking this up but nothing. Pls let me know how to fix this.
Alternatively I tried localhost/myfoldername in my browser, and the Wordpress installation begun with language selection and then the 'lets go' button, then the form to be filled out.
Can I proceed this way or would it involve issues later

Comment: This post should answer your question [WAMPServer 2.5 Homepage the Your Projects Menu and Virtual Hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL it tries to redirect you, probably gives you just "wordpress". Not sure if it's a bug in WampServer index.php or something that needs to be configured, just type http://localhost/wordpress (or how your wp folder is named) to your browser?

Comment: Alternatively I tried localhost/myfoldername in my browser, and the Wordpress installation begun with language selection and then the 'lets go' button, then the form to be filled out. Can I proceed this way or would it involve issues later

Comment: Well, best way to figure that out is to try :) 

No but seriously, can't remember if there are any more issues upcoming, as long as you have write access to your www-folder (which you have) and you have database running, you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit similar problem. It can be by using bad folder to enter your page.

1) You have only wordpress or anything else on your server? If the other pages are ok, i will try jylipaa's option. If it doesn't try to change localhost for 127.0.0.1:8080 or 80 - that port is standard for wamp, xampp, or vertrigo.

2) All pages doing it? This question can be rather non-relating but do you use skype? IF yes, it often happened that skype roguely take port 8080 for himself and don't let you know that. Try to configure your wamp to another port and use http://localhost:81/ for your instalation. That was option i tried and now everything is ok.

Hope this will help.

Comment: going with localhost/myprojectname opened wordpress local installation. I've already done it and its working. had iis port conflict issues so assigned 8080 to it and kept 80 for wamp. dont have skype. thanks for your interest, both of us and jylpiaa are on the mark with this one